# ¿Como puedo conectarme a todos los tipos de proxy posibles en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

como puedo conectarme a un proxy, sea sock4 o sock5, http o https, ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?, gracias por su colaboración, y una cosa más sin importancia,¿como puedo marcar la respuesta que más me guste ?

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada por favor lee [ask] y realiza el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via parámetros o constructores.
Te pongo ejemplos

#### request

Paquete fácil de implementar `pip install requests`
Muy senzillo, en la URL defines el tipo ( socks4, socks5) como también el transporte si proceda ( https )

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

También:

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port',
    'https': 'socks5://user:pass@host:port'
}
```

Para mas detalle, te paso la [documentacion oficial](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) de parámetros proxy

#### pycurl

En el caso de [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html)  es un poco distinto, ya que solemente es un paquete de interface directa al `libcurl` en `c`. Le llaman `C bindings`. Hay poca documentacion en python, ya que solo son `bindings`.

[Tienes que buscar las opciones en la documetacion de `c` y es algo mas costoso](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html).

```
query = pycurl.Curl()
  query.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
  query.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost')
  query.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, SOCKS_PORT)
  query.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME)
  query.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
  query.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)
```